# Why combining flask with apache2 server is better?

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi

A recent flask application I wrote needed to be on an apache2 server. I successfully completed connecting apache and flask but I still wonder why using apache and wsgi is better than just saying "python main.py" and just running the server on port 8080 with port 80 forwarding to 8080?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run your sever directly with python on a port, using Flask, then the server will be single threaded with your requests.  Your performance will suffer.

[How many concurrent requests does a single Flask process receive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938360/how-many-concurrent-requests-does-a-single-flask-process-receive)