# How can I handle multiple Python requests on my AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Flask app deployed on Elastic Beanstalk onto an EC2 instance on AWS. If 100 people simultaneously connected to my server, then wouldn't that mean that they have to wait in a queue of 100 since the app can only handle one instance at a time?

How can I make it so that I can handle more requests using the same IP address to connect to? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is to use `uWSGI` or `gunicorn`.

The longer answer is that your intuition is correct - what you are worrying about is "concurrency", or the number of simultaneous requests your app can handle. And yes, a single Flask app without any application server can handle one request at a time. How do you change that? For most Python apps, the unit of concurrency is a process (there are frameworks that change that, but the majority of app deployments are probably process-based). That is, you run a process for each concurrent request you think you'll need. App servers like `uWSGI` do the listening for your app, then dispatch the request to a process from a pool. So, how many processes do you need?

The second concept you need is "throughput" - how many requests can be served in a specific time, which is influenced by, but different from, "concurrency" and is where your intuition may mislead you. Let's say you have 8 processes. You may think "but I'll have 100 users, 8 is clearly not enough". Let's assume you know that each request completes in 1/8 (.125) seconds. That means that each process can serve 8 requests a second. Times 8 processes; your throughput will be (roughly) 64 requests per second. 8 process gets you a lot closer to your 100 users than you may have otherwise expected. Your 100 users probably won't actually issue requests in that 1 second window. Possible, but unlikely. The issue isn't really the concurrency, but whether the user gets a response in a reasonable time.

Hope this helps. Scaling is a wonderful topic - both straightforward and frustratingly nuanced at the same time. As your traffic increases, the above guidance will shift and you'll need more and more advanced techniques. But to get started - keep it simple and focus on the basics.

See [How many concurrent requests does a single Flask process receive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938360/how-many-concurrent-requests-does-a-single-flask-process-receive)