# How to convert a multiprocess Flask/unicorn to a single multithreaded process

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

I would like to cache a large amount of data in a Flask application. Currently it runs on K8S pods with the following unicorn.ini

```
bind = "0.0.0.0:5000"
workers = 10
timeout = 900
preload_app = True
```

To avoid caching the same data in those 10 workers I would like to know if Python supports a way to multi-thread instead of multi-process. This would be very easy in Java but I am not sure if it is possible in Python. I know that you can share cache between Python instances using the file system or other methods. However it would be a lot simpler if it is all share in the same process space.

Edited:
There are couple post that suggested threads are supported in Python. This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13929101/1077748) by Filipe Correia, or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10942272/1077748) in the same question.

Based on the above comment the Unicorn design [document](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#how-many-threads) talks about workers and threads:

> Since Gunicorn 19, a threads option can be used to process requests in multiple threads. Using threads assumes use of the gthread worker.

Based on how Java works, to shared some data among threads, I would need one worker and multiple threads. Based on this other [link](https://medium.com/building-the-system/gunicorn-3-means-of-concurrency-efbb547674b7)
I know it is possible. So I assume I can change my gunicorn configuration as follows:

```
bind = "0.0.0.0:5000"
workers = 1
threads = 10
timeout = 900
preload_app = True
```

This should give me 1 worker and 10 threads which should be able to process the same number of request as current configuration. However the question is: Would the cache still be instantiated once and shared among all the threads? How or where should I instantiate the cache to make sure is shared among all the threads.

Answer (score 0):

> would like to ... multi-thread instead of multi-process.

I'm not sure you really want that. Python is rather different from Java.

> ```
> workers = 10
> ```

One way to read that is "ten cores", sure.
But another way is "wow, we get ten GILs!"
The global interpreter lock must be held
before the interpreter interprets a new bytecode instruction.

Ten interpreters offers significant parallelism,
executing ten instructions simultaneously.
Now, there *are* workloads dominated by async I/O, or where
the interpreter calls into a C extension to do the bulk of the work.
If a C thread can keep running, doing useful work
in the background, and the interpreter gathers the result later,
terrific. But that's not most workloads.

tl;dr: You probably want ten GILs, rather than just one.

---

> To avoid caching the same data in those 10 workers

Right! That makes perfect sense.

Consider pushing the cache into a storage layer, or a daemon like [Redis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis).

Or access memory-resident cache, in the context of your own process,
via [`mmap`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) or [`shmat`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/shmat).

---

When running Flask under Gunicorn, you are certainly free
to [set `threads`](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html) greater than 1,
though it's likely not what you want.
YMMV. Measure and see.

Comment: The comment by Filipe Correia in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13929101/1077748) seems to suggest that threads are supported by Python.